# WooCommerce Help - Don't send email to user if product is downloadable

Tags: woocommerce

When I configured WooCommerce 'New order' email settings, I wrote two emails (email1@domain.com, email2@domain.com) in Recipient(s) field.

My needs are:
- When the user buy a downloadable product, send email to email1
- When the user buy a normal product, send email to email1 and email2

I've looking through the code of WooCommerce, and it was impossible to implement a function or some code to do this...

Can anyone give me a clue or help to do this, please?

Thank you!

Comment: I don't see a way to modify the new order recipients based on the order. I suspect you will need to right a custom email class (mostly similar to the new order class) that will check for the presence of downloadable products. Start with [how to add a custom woocommerce email](http://www.skyverge.com/blog/how-to-add-a-custom-woocommerce-email/) and come back if you get stuck.

Comment: @helgatheviking you can use the woocommerce abstract `woocommerce_email_recipient_` filter. By putting in the email you're targeting you can modify the recipients. See my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Tested code:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_recipient_new_order', 'so_28025177', 10, 2 );
function so_28025177( $recipients, $order_object  ) {

        $email_one  =  'downloadable@example.com';
        $email_two  =  'physical@example.com';

        $wc_order     =  new WC_Order( $order_object->id );
        $order_items  =  $wc_order->get_items( );

        $has_downloadable  =  false;
        $has_physical      =  false;

        foreach( $order_items as $item ) {

                $product_id  =  $item[ 'product_id' ];

                $product_meta  =  get_post_meta( $product_id, '_downloadable', true );

                if( $product_meta  ==  'yes' ) {
                        $has_downloadable  =  true;
                }
                elseif( $product_meta  ==  'no' ) {
                        $has_physical  =  true;
                }

        }

        if( $has_downloadable && ! $has_physical ) {
                $recipients .=  ',' . $email_one;
        }
        elseif ( $has_physical && ! $has_downloadable ) {
                $recipients .=  ',' . $email_two;
        }
        elseif ( $has_downloadable && $has_physical ) {
                $recipients .=  ',' . $email_one . ',' . $email_two;
        }

        return $recipients;

}
```

Comment: Wow !! Thank you a lot Dez !!! Is there a possibility to get the recipients entered in the admin field??

Comment: Good work @Dez. I just wasn't sure that the `$order` was passed to that filter. I thought that was the `$email` class object. +1

Comment: @user3800667 the '$recipients' variable starts out as those entered in the admin field. I'll update my answer to include those.